# How do I use bean validation effectively in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: forms, model, playframework, playframework-2.0, bean-validation

Using Play Framework 2, I'm trying to get "required" validation working, with a custom message using this example code:

**A simple Student model:**

```
@Id                    private Long      id;    
@Required              private String    studentName;
@Required  @ManyToOne  private Classroom classroom;
```

**A simple Student form (view):**

```
@inputText(form("studentName"), '_label -> "Student Name", '_help -> "Please enter name.")
@select(form("classroom.id"), options(Classroom.options), '_label -> "Class", '_default -> "-- Choose an Classroom --")
```

**1.** The validation DOES work for the text input but DOES NOT work for the select box. The default value of the select box. Why?

**2.** Also, when the error is displayed, I get 2 messages. Both the help text and the validation message. Any ideas how I can just get one custom message?

Comment: Any links to detailed documentation or sample code MUCH appreciated.

Comment: @nico_ekito I always accept answers that are correct and useful :) I think I just ask nasty questions that no one can or is willing to answer :(

Answer (score 1):

1. You can hide the constraints by adding '_showConstraints -> false' to your input fields in the views.
2. To add custom error messages in your controller, you can use

   myform.reject("field","error message")

Where field should equal the name of your entity property and the name of your input element.

I'm still figuring out Play just like you, so I'm not sure on the correct approach on how to solve your selectlist problem, but I'd debug your application and see if your form doesn't contain any validation errors anyway but it just doesn't show them.

Comment: Thanks @Moeri, I'd love to know if you have any further ideas on why the select box doesn't work, and also how to make a custom error from the bean...